# self-similar solution for heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve this question from Salsa's PDE in action:
[image]

If we let $u = t^{\alpha}U(\xi)$ , where $\xi = x/t^{\beta}$, and

$$u_t = t^{\alpha-1}\left(\alpha U(\xi) - \beta\ \xi U'(\xi)\right)$$

$$ u_{xx} = t^{\alpha - 2 \beta} U''(\xi)$$

then for part a), letting $\beta = 1/2$, we get:

$$u_t - u_{xx} = t^{\alpha-1}\left(\alpha U(\xi) - \frac{\xi}{2} U'(\xi) - U''(\xi)\right) = 0$$

and for part b, letting $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 1/2$

$$u_t - u_{xx} = 1\cdot \left( U(\xi) - \frac{\xi}{2} U'(\xi) - U''(\xi)\right) = 1$$

and same thing for part $c$.

My question is how to prove that the given parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are appropriate for each $f(x)$. I don't see how

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense to me. The specific values of $\alpha, \beta$ in each case are appropriate because they leave the equation invariant. That's it.

Comment: You mean the given question or my question? If it is the latter, how to show that it is invariant with these specific parameters? Or put simply, how to answer the given question as it is written!

Comment: Have you tried solving the corresponding ODE for $U$?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Yes wolframalpha gives a series solution which was not hepful

Comment: Note that $x = t^{\beta} \xi$ so you are trying to find the values of $\alpha, \beta$ such that $t^{\alpha-1} = t^{\alpha-2\beta} = t^{\beta}$. Solving, $$\beta = \alpha-1 \implies \alpha-1 = \alpha-2(\alpha-1) \implies \alpha-1 = -\alpha+2 \implies \alpha = 3/2 \implies \beta = \dots$$